# Why does the shape of Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution depends on temperature, but not mass and number of particles?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, probability

My physics textbook provided the following probability density function for speed of particle in an ideal gas under a certain temperature.
$$f(v)=4\pi N\left(\frac{m}{2\pi k T}\right)^{3/2} v^{2} e^{-mv^{2}/2kT}$$

Below is the graph.

[image]

Why does the shape depends on temperature?

Can't I just keep increase $N$ to an extremely large number and thus increase the probability for extremely high speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As one can see from the expression in the OP, the shape is independent on the number of particles - increasing $N$ only increases the height of the distribution, i.e., it only changes the scale on the $y$ axis.

However, unlike it is suggested by the title, the distribution is dependent on the particle mass - the curves would look differently, if it were a gas other than nitrogen.

Comment: No, as you see from the graph it doesn't. It is also seen from the mathematical form: $f$ is proportional to $v^2$ which increases and to $e^{-mv^2/(2kT)}$ which decreases with $v$. In teh begining $v^2$ dominates and the curve rises, but then the exponent wins, and the curve drops.

Comment: Thank you, I rushed to a conclusion without actually reviewing the basic math properties.